# How to specify amount of characters per line on a fasta file

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta

I have a fasta file that looks like this:

```
>abc
AGAATTCGTCTTGCTCTATTCACCCTTACTTTTCTTCTTGCCCGTTCTCTTTCTTAGTATGAATCCAGTA
TGCCTGCCTGTAATTGTTGCGCCCTACCTCTTTTGGCTGGCGGCTATTGCCGCCTCGTGTTTCACGGCCT
CAGTTAGTACCGTTGTGACCGCCACCGGCTTGGCCCTCTCACTTCTACTCTTGGCAGCAGTGGCCAGCTC
ATATGCCGCTGCACAAAGGAAACTGCTGACACCGGTGACAGTGCTTACTGCGGTTGTCACTTGTGAGTAC
```

However, I need the file to have 60 characters per line. It should look like this:

```
   >abc
    AGAATTCGTCTTGCTCTATTCACCCTTACTTTTCTTCTTGCCCGTTCTCTTTCTTAGTAT
    GAATCCAGTATGCCTGCCTGTAATTGTTGCGCCCTACCTCTTTTGGCTGGCGGCTATTGC
    CGCCTCGTGTTTCACGGCCTCAGTTAGTACCGTTGTGACCGCCACCGGCTTGGCCCTCTC
    ACTTCTACTCTTGGCAGCAGTGGCCAGCTCATATGCCGCTGCACAAAGGAAACTGCTGAC
```

I tried to use fold -w 60 myfile.fasta > out.fa to change my file but the output is not what I expected. The output file looks like this:

```
>abc
AGAATTCGTCTTGCTCTATTCACCCTTACTTTTCTTCTTGCCCGTTCTCTTTCTTAGTAT
GAATCCAGTA
TGCCTGCCTGTAATTGTTGCGCCCTACCTCTTTTGGCTGGCGGCTATTGCCGCCTCGTGT
TTCACGGCCT
CAGTTAGTACCGTTGTGACCGCCACCGGCTTGGCCCTCTCACTTCTACTCTTGGCAGCAG
TGGCCAGCTC
ATATGCCGCTGCACAAAGGAAACTGCTGACACCGGTGACAGTGCTTACTGCGGTTGTCAC
TTGTGAGTAC
ACACGCACCATTTACAATGCATGATGTTCGTGAGATTGATCTGTCTCTAACAGTTCACTT
```

Is there another way I can manipulate my fasta file to get it to the format I need?

Comment: Is it seqkit you are trying to use. What seqkit command did you run? See my solution below. It work fine in my hands.

Answer (score 2):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use common bioinformatics tools, preferably open source tools. For example, you can use [`seqtk`](https://github.com/lh3/seqtk) tool like so:

```
seqtk seq -l N infile > outfile
```

**EXAMPLES:**

```
$ echo ">seq1\nACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG\nACTG" | seqtk seq -l 60 
>seq1
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
ACTGACTG

$ echo ">seq1\nACTG\nACTG" | seqtk seq -l 60
>seq1
ACTGACTG
```

To install these tools, use `conda`, specifically `miniconda`, for example:

```
conda create --channel bioconda --name seqtk seqtk
conda activate seqtk
# ... use seqtk here ...
conda deactivate
```

**REFERENCES:**

`seqtk`: https://github.com/lh3/seqtk
`conda`: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have listed two options below. Hope it helps.

```
seqkit seq input.fasta -w 60
```

Instructions for [seqkit](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/) is here.

And it's very easy to install using conda:
https://anaconda.org/bioconda/seqkit

A second option is to use Python's textwrap module. You could first parse the FASTA file with Biopython then use textwrap on the the string.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import textwrap

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("input.fasta", "fasta"):
    dna = str(seq_record.seq)
    fasta_record=textwrap.fill(dna, width=30)
    print(">",seq_record.id)
    print(fasta_record)
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the Python's textwrap module.

Answer (score 0):

with python

```
with open("yourfile", "r") as f:
   text = f.read().split("\n",1)
   text[1] = text[1].replace("\n",'')
   text = text[0]+"\n"+"\n".join(" "+text[1][i*60:(i*60)+60] for i in range(len(text[1])//60))
   print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne 'sub out { print substr $buff, 0, 60, "" while $buff; print $_ }
           if (/^>/) { out() }
           else { $buff .= $_ }
           END { out() }
    ' file.fasta
```

- `-n` reads the file line by line and runs the code for each line;
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`;
- We store the non-header lines in `$buff`;
- When a header line (or end of file) arrives, we print the buffer 60 characters at a time.